# How can i add the label of a number above geom_point?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to add the label of a number above `geom_point` using `geom_text` with no success. I want to show the calories intake of each fruit. It is clear on the x-axis, but i would like to write the label of each number above the dot point in the plot. Could someone help please?

[image]

Here is the data and the code:

```
df= structure(list(fruit = structure(1:3, .Label = c("Orange", "Banana", 
                                                     "Kiwi"), class = "factor"), term = c("calories", "calories", "calories"), 
                   calories = c(47, 89, 61
                   )), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")


df %>%
  ggplot(aes(calories, fruit)) + 
  geom_point(mapping=aes(x=calories, y=fruit), size=5)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `geom_label()` will do the job.

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = calories, y = fruit)) + 
  geom_point(size=5) + 
  geom_label(label = df$calories)
```

You can use the `nudge_x` and `nudge_y` arguments to set where the labels go in relation to the point.

Comment: geom_text should work just as fine given with small nudge towards higher y...